# Product feed with 2 Facebook Page

Tags: magento2, product, module, facebook

I have the Facebook Ads extension plugin with Magento.
I already have it configured with one Facebook Page with the product feed.
Is it possible to add another page and a second product feed? The two feeds have different parameters (currency).